# How do you take an user input?

Tags: q#

How do you take an user input as integer or string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this as part of a Main method in your C# or Python driver code, or you could use the new support for Q# command-line executables called out in the recent release ([0.11.2004.2825](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/relnotes/#version-01120042825)). If you follow the link for the quantum random number generator sample and scroll down, you'll see an [example there](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/quantum/quickstarts/qrng?tabs=tabid-qsharp#creating-a-complete-random-number-generator) for using `@EntryPoint()` to denote the Q# operation that should be used to generate the entry point code. It will also cause any arguments to that operation to automatically become command-line parameters for the built executable. You can try this in the sample by updating the code to take `max` as an argument, like this:

```
@EntryPoint()
operation SampleRandomNumber(max : Int) : Int {
    Message($"Sampling a random number between 0 and {max}: ");
    return SampleRandomNumberInRange(max);
}
```

Then when you run the sample via `dotnet run` you'll see that it now requires `--max` as a command line parameter, and handles the translation into the correct input type for the Q# operation. You can then pass the param like this to get the same behavior as the original sample: `dotnet run --max 50`

Hope that helps!